# Magento - CatalogSearch Module overriding not working

Tags: php, magento

I want to override the "prepareProductCollection" function of layer in core CatalogSearch module. This is what I have written:

File Path:`Company/Module/Model/CatalogSearch/Layer.php`

```
class Company_Module_Model_CatalogSearch_Layer extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer
{
public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
{
    parent::prepareProductCollection($collection);

    Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->addCatalogInventoryToProductCollection($collection);

    $collection->getSelect()->order('is_in_stock desc');
    return $this;
}
}
```

And in the config file:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        <Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
               <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                   <layer>Company_Module_Model_CatalogSearch_Layer</layer>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I think I might be missing something? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You missed ending the `catalogsearch` tag in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

add require_once(app/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer) at the top

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do the exact same thing.
I followed multiple tutorials and tried several things. In the end I ended up having 503 errors all the time (without any maintanance.flag file - other shop sites worked well).
But I managed to fix that. I will show you what I have now and also what the reason for the 503 was, in case someone stumbles across that problem:

I've named the Module Company/CatalogSearch and it is made up of three files:

app/code/local/Company/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php :

```
<?php
class Company_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer {

    public function prepareProductCollection($collection) {

        parent::prepareProductCollection($collection);

        // YOUR CODE HERE

        return $this;
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Company/CatalogSearch/etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_CatalogSearch>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Company_CatalogSearch>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer>Company_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer</layer>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Company_CatalogSearch.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_CatalogSearch>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_CatalogSearch>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And that's all.

To the 503 problem:
In the file app/code/local/Company/CatalogSearch/etc/config.xml I had

```
<rewrite>
    <layer>
        Company_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer
    </layer>
</rewrite>
```

instead of

```
<rewrite>
    <layer>Company_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer</layer>
</rewrite>
```

Hope that helps!